# Grunt zetzer options

Tags: html, gruntjs

I am trying to pass a class to an include with grunt zetzer but I am not able to take it into the include.
I mean I invoque the part

```
{{= it.include("common/entity-slider-hero.html", {"class" : "extraclass","link" : "http://www.optionlink"}) }}
```

It works fine, but how do I get the option in the include?... something like
`<div class="hero-slider {it.{class}} "` >

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the solution the correct way was {{= it.class}}